# PHP mail(); How to set charset for subject and email

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, phpmailer

I'm using the following code to send an e-mail:

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "Subject!";
$message = "Hello!";
$headers = "From: Me<example@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: example@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: example@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Although using `charset=utf-8` the characters in the subject and the email address line still doesn't get decoded right. I'm getting characters like this: `Ã¶ÃŸÃ¤`.

How can I set the charset for subject and email address line, too?

Comment: Did you check the answer provided? Please accept it if it's correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To encode the subject of an email you should use:

```
$subject = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
```

And then inside the `mail` function:

```
mail($to,$subject,...);
```

Comment: Can I do: `mail($to,'=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=',$message,$headers);`?

Comment: Yes  it's exactly the same

Comment: I tried the same with `$to` but that seems not to work. E-Mail comes back as undeliverable. What can I do?

Comment: You have email address that has unicode chars in it?

Comment: Like that: `$headers = "From: ÄÖÜß<example@example.com>\r\n";`

Comment: Your question was regarding the subject and the answer is correct according to the question. The `from` is different (you should open a new question regarding this, or search stackoverflow/google).

Comment: No, please read my question. It's about the subject AND the email address line.

Comment: Stop reinventing the wheel. Use a library. It will also avoid the vulnerabilities you've written, and encode the headers correctly.

Comment: @Synchro I agree with that, but sometimes you want to understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend reading the RFCs (they're not that hard!), and also looking at existing implementations, such as PHPMailer that you tagged this question with, to see how they do it. Naive code all too often gets deployed and forgotten about, and thus are vulnerabilities born...

Comment: @Synchro I don't like using libraries.

Comment: Well have fun when your sites get hacked, and may you waste many pointless hours producing trivial code that's been written better elsewhere.

Comment: @David I believe my answer is correct. Will appreciate if you accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Using a library for just sending a simple confirmation mail is overkill. Also, libraries have vulnerabilities too, especially if they themselves depend on other libraries and so forth...